# Sqlite compiler errors in Debug mode "initializer is not a constant"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, sqlite

I'm trying to add sqlite to my project, but I'm getting several "initializer is not a constant" errors. For some reason this only happen in Debug mode, and not in Release mode.

A line its crashing on is for exmaple line 97668 from sqlite3.c:

```
static const int iLn = __LINE__+2;
```

Any ideas on why this is happening / how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard specifies that `__LINE__` is a constant.

When Visual Studio's "Edit and Continue" is enabled, line numbers might change.
This function might be useful, but is not compatible will all programs.

Compile `sqlite3.c` separately without debugging, or disable "Edit and Continue".

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting it with

```
#define iLn (__LINE__+2)
```